# Reputation decreases

Tags: discussion, reputation, lost-reputation

Yesterday I saw my reputation as 1024. I didn't have any activity on Stack Overflow. But today it shows reputation as 910. What is reason for this?

Answer (score 5):

Probably, one of your post got flagged as spam/offensive, check at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and look for -100 post

---

Quick calculations on your posts is like this

```
From Questions       : 240
From Answers         : 875
Bounty you've set    : -100 (two 50 bounties)
Got Downvoted        : -46
Answers you accepted : 38
Downvotes you gave   : -7
Initial              : 1
---------------------------
                    ~ 1001 (approximately)
```

Now you have 910, so you are losing around 100, so most likely it was because of a post, which got flagged as spam/offensive (6 flags needed to be happened)

Comment: Or he could have answered a question which got deleted. If a re-calc happened (happens for various reasons) then his rep would also go down, and the missing rep would not appear in /reputation